# Creating a new dataframe based on a condition between two columns of original dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe with 3 columns as below :

```
X Y Z
1 4 2
2 3 3
3 1 4
```

I want to create a data frame where the third column is substituted with values of the first column if it matches with the second column. As I have shown with an example output below :

```
X Y Z=(X+1)
1 4 NA
2 3 2
3 1 NA
```

The code I have tried is as follows :

```
library(dplyr)
chk4 %>% chk5
chk4 %>% if(X == Z)
mutate(# Z value to Y where X = Y)
```

Comment: Unclear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: I just added an example as well.

Comment: `df$Z = ifelse( df$Z == df$Y, df$X, NA)`

Comment: not working yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to substitute values in column Z with values from X if Y values equals Z or with NA if not then do:

```
df$Z = ifelse( df$Z == df$Y, df$X, NA)
```

where `df` is your data frame.

Example:

```
df = data.frame(X = c(1,2,3), Y = c(4,3,1), Z = c(2,3,4))
df$Z = ifelse( df$Z == df$Y, df$X, NA)

df
  X Y  Z
1 1 4 NA
2 2 3  2
3 3 1 NA
```